# Perforce , Perl , how to work with the client

Tags: perl, perforce

I am new to the Perforce source control and I am trying to build a script that login to the server and get files to the working directory. Now I am able to connect to the server, set the working folder but I can not get the client.

This is the code of the connection to the server

```
$p4 = new P4;

$p4->SetProg($ScriptName);
$p4->SetVersion($ScriptRevision);
$p4->SetCharset($ENV{P4_CHARSET}); 
$p4->SetPort ($ENV{P4_IP_AND_PORT});
$p4->SetClient($ENV{P4_CLIENT});
$p4->SetUser($ENV{P4_USER});
$p4->SetPassword($ENV{P4_PWD}); 

$p4->Connect() or die "blblblblblb" ;

$p4->SetCwd($Working_dir); ## the dir exists
```

Now I need to create the client. Is this is the way ?

```
$p4->FetchClient( $ENV{P4_CLIENT} );
```

I am getting back an object , but the 
Runsync command fail with error
Client 'xxxxxx' unknown - use 'client' command to create it

My question is how to create the client in Perl and how to use it in the sync command.

Answer (score 2):

To create the client in P4Perl, you'll need to:

1. Construct the spec data for the new client, either field-by-field, or by using a template client.
2. Issue `$p4->SaveClient( $clientspec );` with your spec data.

Then, once you've created your client spec that describes your workspace, you'll need to tell P4Perl to use that client spec for your commands: `$p4->SetClient( 'my-client-name' );`

Then you can run your sync command.

Comment: Or simply just create a client in the P4V GUI, if that's an option, before using it in your Perl script.

Comment: thanks for the help, what I did is to use the client command  with the -o  option  , edit , save and set the spec